# Macedonian in TexShop

Tags: xetex

```
\XeTeXinputencoding utf-8
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}    

\newcommand{\clrpg}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}

\hyphenation{био-мар-ке-ри ис-тра-жу-ва-ње-то мо-ле-ку-лар-ни-те про-це-си ко-ло-рек-та-лен он-то-ло-гии пред-ви-ду-ва-ње} 

\begin{document} 

\maketitle           

\begin{abstract}

In numerous educational institutes, learning management systems are vital parts of delivering class materials not only for on-line courses but also on-campus classes. The primary determination of learning management system is to provide proper virtual educational environments and suitable communicational channels between instructors and students letting them to overcome the barrier of time and space for the general schooling. We will investigate the security vulnerability in such learning management systems. Particularly, we will examine the vulnerability discovery process in the two popular learning management systems, Moodle and Blackboard. There are applied two vulnerability discovery models to inspect the vulnerability discovery process quantitatively.
The discovery models permits to estimate the approximate number of vulnerability likely to be discovered in software systems in the future. It also helps policy makers when they need to decide which learning management systems will be adopted for their organizations when security is an extremely important factor. Result shows that the vulnerability discovery process in learning management systems could be predictable which could be used for IT risk valuation in organizations having the systems.

\bf Keywords: Moodle, Blackboard, learning management system, vulnerability, quantitative analysis.

I have to translate this abstract in Macedonian, but when I compile it with XeLatex it gives me an error at hyphenation. 

\end{abstract}
```

Comment: please show a small complete document that you expect to make output, your current example produces no text

Comment: Please provide a complete example which produces the error and tell us the exact error message you receive.

Comment: \hyphenation{??????????} error is shown like this (the text which is written in macedonian) and I can not compile it. If you have any other suggestion how to include Macedonian, please let me know.

Comment: have you tried the complete document as shown in my answer, it runs without error. note I do not know Macedonian but wikipedia suggests it is similar to Bulgarian? the tex distributions include bulgarian hyphenation patterns so if you specified that language it may be that you do not need so many \hyphenation exceptions.

Comment: please show the _exact_ error from the log file from `!` to `?` in a code section `{}` in the question, so that line breaks are preserved in the error message.

Comment: @ErmiraIdrizi, any news?

Answer (score 1):

You should get no error from the code you posted once it is a complete document with `\documentclass`, there are however some unneeded commands. As you are using xetex I have used `polyglossia` to set up language switching I hope that that makes hyphenation good enough, I do not know either language so I can not test.

here "Abstract" has been translated by polyglossia, if that is wrong the correct translation can be provided. The actual text is google translate to Macedonian (I have no idea if it is even close, sorry)

The result with xelatex looks like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bulgarian}% sorry closest in polyglossia I think
%\XeTeXinputencoding utf-8
\usepackage{fontspec}%,xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}    

\newcommand{\clrpg}{\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}

%\hyphenation{био-мар-ке-ри ис-тра-жу-ва-ње-то мо-ле-ку-лар-ни-те про-це-си ко-ло-рек-та-лен он-то-ло-гии пред-ви-ду-ва-ње} 

\title{foo}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle           

\begin{abstract}

In numerous educational institutes, learning management systems are
vital parts of delivering class materials not only for on-line
courses but also on-campus classes. The primary determination of
learning management system is to provide proper virtual educational
environments and suitable communicational channels between
instructors and students letting them to overcome the barrier of
time and space for the general schooling. We will investigate the
security vulnerability in such learning management
systems. Particularly, we will examine the vulnerability discovery
process in the two popular learning management systems, Moodle and
Blackboard. There are applied two vulnerability discovery models to
inspect the vulnerability discovery process quantitatively.

The discovery models permits to estimate the approximate number of
vulnerability likely to be discovered in software systems in the
future. It also helps policy makers when they need to decide which
learning management systems will be adopted for their organizations
when security is an extremely important factor. Result shows that the
vulnerability discovery process in learning management systems could
be predictable which could be used for IT risk valuation in
organizations having the systems.

\textbf{Keywords}: Moodle, Blackboard, learning management system, vulnerability, quantitative analysis.

\end{abstract}

I have to translate this abstract in Macedonian, but when I compile it with XeLatex it gives me an error at hyphenation. 

\begin{bulgarian}
\begin{abstract}

Во бројни образовни институции, учење системи за управување се витални делови на доставување класа материјали не само за on-line курсеви, но, исто така, на кампусот класи. Примарната определба на учење систем за управување е да се обезбеди соодветна виртуелни образовни средини и соодветни канали за комуникација помеѓу инструктори и студенти да им се овозможи да ги надмине бариерата на време и простор за општата школување. Ние ќе ги испита безбедност ранливоста во ваквите системи за управување со учење. Особено, ќе разгледаме процесот на откривање ранливост во две популарни системи за управување со учење, Moodle и Изи. Таму се применуваат две откривање ранливост модели да ги провери откритие процес ранливост квантитативно.

Дозволи откривањето модели за да се процени на приближниот број на ранливост, најверојатно, ќе бидат откриени во софтверски системи во иднина. Таа, исто така им помага на креаторите на политиката, кога тие треба да се одлучи кој ќе биде усвоен учење системи за управување за нивните организации, кога безбедноста е исклучително важен фактор. Резултат покажува дека процесот на откривање ранливост во учење системи за управување може да биде предвидлив кои би можеле да се користат за проценка на ризикот од несоодветност на организациите кои имаат системи.

\textbf{Клучни зборови}: Мудл, Изи, учење систем за управување, ранливост, квантитативна анализа.
\end{abstract}
\end{bulgarian}

\end{document}
```